# Enable and Disable look and feel of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have `Recylerview` on my `Activity`.I can disable recylerview items selection using below code

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                // true: consume touch event
                // false: dispatch touch event
                return touch;
            }
        });
```

But I want below functionality to show disable/enable look and feel

Enabled RV:

[image]

on Switching off,Disabled all or some items in `RecylerView` as below

[image]

I guess its kind some transparent view over `RecyclerView' as items are still clickable because I can see ripple effect on items click but functionality not works on disable. how  can achieve this behavior in my application

Comment: This one look like preference Activity or Fragment and this one is enabled or disable functionality.

Comment: yeah  I know that. but  want to know how to achieve this functionality in recylerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After disabling the recyclerview from above code, change the **opacity** of each row and setEnable(False) for each row item and while enabling the recyclerview remove the opacity and setEnable(true).

inside the changelistner for toogle button refresh the recyclerview with your changes of opacity and all.

for you information i am adding a simple code:-

```
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                tvText.setEnabled(true);
                tvText.setText("enabled");
                tvText.setAlpha(1);
            }else{
                tvText.setText("disabled");
                tvText.setAlpha(0.4f);
                tvText.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

refresh your recyclerview from if else loop and pass the enable/disable values to it and change the each row's alpha.

Comment: i have added some code please take help of it to understand, apply your logic.

Answer (score 0):

just add transparent view over recycler view and Set **android:clickable="true"** in xml to your foreground view.

Comment: it will effect whole view